# SQL-How To Perform Query on Newly Created Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a full_name column, and then I create a new column based on it.

however i cannot perform aggregate or other kinds of functions on this new column.

how do we bypass this?

```
select full_name, 
case when full_name like '%b%' then 1 else 0 end as sample,
sum(sample)
from table
```

Comment: There is not much point of showing the list of 1 or 0 in a column and the aggregated value as the aggregated value would have to be repeated along all rows. This is sql, not excel. If you are only interested in the sum, then you can use conditional aggregation directly (aka pivoting), which has tons of examples already here on SO. Please clarify what your expected out should look like!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query you just need to use conditional aggregation as below:

```
select full_name, 
       sum(case when full_name like '%b%' then 1 else 0 end) as sample
from table
group by full_name;
```

> [MySQL
> Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)
>
> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
> different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
> clauses to refer to the column:

More complicated way would be using an outer query as below which is pointless and excess :

```
   select full_name,
           sum(sample) as b_name_sum
   from ( select full_name, 
                  case when full_name like '%b%' then 1 else 0 end as sample
           from table
          ) as b_name                                              
 group by full_name;
```